# Constructing a vector with istream_iterators is slower than a while loop with string / std::atof, why?

Tags: c++, linux, performance, optimization, g++

I'm reading a stream of values in from std::cin, and constructing a std::vector from it.  Originally, I used a while loop with a temporary std::string object, and used std::atof with the c_str() from the temporary string.  There's a few calls in there, and generally a lot going on.  I replaced it with the range constructor, using std::istream_iterator with std::cin, thinking it would look simpler, and be quicker.  To my surprise, it was a bit slower, though it does look cleaner.

My question is this:  Why, in the code below, is the construction of std::vector using std::istream_iterator slower than the alternative method, using a mashup of function calls?  Also, is there a way to modify the range construction using say, std::istreambuf_iterator, such that the performance of the two methods are equivalent? I've seen answers stating that I should add `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);` to the code.  While this increases the performance, it does so in both cases, and a difference between the two methods still exists.

**Minimal Working Example**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    /* Faster Method */
    string temporary_line{};
    vector<double> data{};
    while(cin>> temporary_line)
        data.push_back(atof(temporary_line.c_str()));  

    /* Slower Method */
    //vector<double> data{ istream_iterator<double>{cin},
    //                     stream_iterator<double>{} };

    cout<< data.back() << '\n';
}
```

I ran the code through 5 different compilers, g++-{7,8}, and clang++-{6,7,8}.  The code was compiled under -O2 for all runs, with each time representing the average of 5 runs.  The times were tight enough that adding more trials wouldn't have mattered.  The results show the same behavior across all compilers, with g++ edging out clang++ by just a small amount of time on both methods.

[image]

To test, create a file of ~1,000,000 random integers:

`$ for i in {0..999999}; do echo $RANDOM >> datafile; done`

To compile:

`$ g++ -o ds descriptive_statistics.cpp -O2`

To run with the generated example data:

`$ time cat datafile | ./ds`

**The full code**:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>
#include <numeric>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class DS {

public:
    DS() = default;
    DS(const DS& ) = default;
    DS(DS&& ) = default;
    DS(const double*, std::size_t length);
    DS(const double*, const double*);
    virtual ~DS() = default;

    DS& operator=(const DS& ) = default;
    DS& operator=(DS&& ) = default;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& , const DS& );

    bool operator<(const DS& ) = delete;
    bool operator>(const DS& ) = delete;
    bool operator==(const DS& ) = delete;

private:
    double min;
    double first_quartile;
    double mean;
    double median;
    double third_quartile;
    double max;
    double sum;
    double variance;
    double standard_deviation;
};

DS::DS(const double* begin, const double* end) {

    const std::size_t size = std::distance(begin, end) ;

    min = *begin;    

    first_quartile = begin[ size/4 ] ;

    sum = std::accumulate(begin, end, double{});

    mean = sum / size ;

    const std::size_t idx{ size  / 2 };
    median = begin[ idx ] ;
    if( ! (size & 1) ) {      
        median += begin[ idx - 1 ];
        median *= 0.5;
    }

    third_quartile = begin[ 3*size/4 ] ; 

    variance = std::accumulate(begin, end, double{}, 
            [&] (double a, double b) {
                return a + std::pow(b - mean, 2.0); 
            }) / size ;

    standard_deviation = std::sqrt(variance);  

    max = *std::prev(end);   
}

DS::DS(const double* begin, std::size_t length) {
    const double* end = begin + length;
    *this = DS(begin,end);
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const DS& ds) {
    os <<  ds.min                << '\n'
       <<  ds.first_quartile     << '\n'
       <<  ds.mean               << '\n'
       <<  ds.median             << '\n'
       <<  ds.third_quartile     << '\n'
       <<  ds.max                << '\n'
       <<  ds.sum                << '\n'
       <<  ds.variance           << '\n'
       <<  ds.standard_deviation << '\n';
    return os;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // This section is faster than the section below
    std::string temporary_line{};
    std::vector<double> data{};
    while(std::cin>> temporary_line) {
        data.push_back(std::atof(temporary_line.c_str()));
    }

    // This section is slower than the section above
    // std::vector<double> data{
    //         std::istream_iterator<double>{std::cin},
    //         std::istream_iterator<double>{}
    // };

    if(! std::is_sorted(data.cbegin(), data.cend()) ) {
        std::sort(data.begin(), data.end());
    }

    DS ds(&*data.cbegin(), &*data.cend());   
    std::cout<< ds << std::endl;

    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: You can make the faster method even faster if you use `reserve` method over the vector, before pushing new items into it (all you need to do is to know ahead how much values [even approximately] you will need, or to do it dynamic and every time that your vector's capacity getting full, reserve more places ahead).

Comment: Your question is limited solely to the issue of parsing input. So, why do you feel it's necessary to have 90% of the shown code utterly and completely irrelevant to the question being asked? How is this "DS" class, and all of its code, related directly to what's being asked here? You could've simply showed five lines of code that reads doubles one way, and another five lines of code that reads doubles the other way, and that would've been perfectly sufficient.

Comment: @KorelK Yes, I could do that.  However, I do not know how many elements I will have.  I am more curious about the internal workings of the vector constructor I suppose, because in either case I'm not pre-allocating

Comment: You might be interested in [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/), btw.

Comment: @KorelK _every time that your vector's capacity getting full, reserve more places ahead_ That's not necessary.  `std::vector` already does that internally.  `reserve` only has value if you (roughly) know the number of elements you need ahead of time.

Comment: How come you only compare how that one compiler performs? `g++` is brilliant at some things. `clang++` does certain stuff very nicely.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik

Your reply comes across a little snarky, and somewhat unprofessional, but I'll explain why.

1) The code isn't that long.  It's a mere 100 lines, with the part in question highlighted. 2) It makes it easier for another SO user to quickly copy and paste into gedit, compile, and run. 3) It shows the exact test case so that another SO user knows where the data is coming from, and how much there should be. 4) It shows how the program should be compiled, ran, and used.  5)  If I were another user, I would have had to write more code just to see the problem.

Comment: @TedLyngmo 

I'm not sure if you posted before I made the first edit or not, but I did try clang++.  The performance gap between the two was even worse than with gcc, but not overly so.  I only tried clang-7, but it's the only one I had on hand at the moment.

Comment: @Shawn 

That actually looks great!  I'd never heard of it before.  Thanks for pointing it out.  It looks like something I was going to try to morph this into anyways.

Comment: @KBentley57 I only saw `g++` so I guess I was late (or early) :-) - but please do present your findings regarding compilers you've tried too.

Comment: @TedLyngmo  I'm running it through a few more compilers, I'll update the post in a few minutes.

Comment: @KBentley57 Nice! Edit the question to make the question more informative when you've gotten results.

Comment: @TedLyngmo  I just posted the results.  When the IO part of the timing is taken into consideration, the difference in executable time is significant.

Comment: @KBentley57 Nice - but reduce the text. I think you have a question that can be asked in one or two lines - so the big wall of text may make those best qualified to answer tired.

Comment: The DS class is not needed. The sorting is not needed. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @n.m. Edited for a min. working compiling code.

Comment: I don't know the specific reason here, but ultimately one way or another it will be the result of iostreams being universally terrible. The modern approach would be to read largeish chunks at a time (eg. 8kiB) and use `std::from_chars` to read the values you want from that.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at the implementation of `std::istream_iterator<double>` you can notice that doing

```
std::vector<double> data{ std::istream_iterator<double>{file},
                             std::istream_iterator<double>{} };
```

is really an equivalent of doing

```
double temporary_line;
std::vector<double> data{};
while (file>>temporary_line) {
      data.push_back(temporary_line);
}
```

See the difference in assembly code on [godbolt](https://www.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Calgorithm%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Citerator%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccmath%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstdint%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstdlib%3E%0A%23include+%3Cmemory%3E%0A%23include+%3Cnumeric%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%23include+%3Clist%3E%0A%0Ausing+namespace+std%3B%0Aint+main(int+argc,+char**+argv)%0A%7B%0A%23ifdef+FIRST%0A++++std::vector%3Cdouble%3E+data%7B+istream_iterator%3Cdouble%3E%7Bcin%7D,%0A+++++++++++++++++++++++++istream_iterator%3Cdouble%3E%7B%7D+%7D%3B%0A%23else%0A%0A++++//This+section+is+slower+than+the+section+above%0A++++double+temporary_line%3B%0A%09std::vector%3Cdouble%3E+data%7B%7D%3B%0A%09while+(std::cin+%3E%3E+temporary_line)+%7B%0A%09%09data.push_back(temporary_line)%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%23endif%0A++++double+i+%3D+0.0%3B%0A++++std::cout%3C%3C+std::accumulate(data.begin(),+data.end(),+i)%3C%3Cstd::endl%3B%0A++++return(EXIT_SUCCESS)%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:35.59198037512264,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'--std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-O2++-DFIRST',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:30.792088178633648,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'--std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-O2+-DSECOND',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:33.61593144624372,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

So your whole question boils down to why `std::atof` is faster than `operator>>`.

As you can notice in O2 with gcc there is a call to `strtod`  instead of `call    std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::_M_extract<double>(double&)` https://www.godbolt.org/z/Od-FIk but the structure of the code is basically the same.

And I believe the reason for time difference is the `locale`. `std::atof` is partly oblivious to the [`locale`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale) (it sees the C locale) on the other hand `operator>>` does the job of parsing with the constraint of the specified `C++ locale` and eventually with a UNICODE encoder.

Doing more complex operation takes more time. But 50% penalty time for taking into account UNICODE and every `locale` isn't that bad, don't you think ?

Comment: You are right. Just saying that sometimes templated function makes you do a little more work than expected (which is basically what you said in your answer) for the sake of generality. And sometimes the extra optimization (the squash the two parsing passes into one) is not done.

Answer (score 1):

The two programs do similar, but really different things.

The `atof` program parses strings that look like C floating point numbers. Their format is fixed. excluding the decimal-point character which is determined by the current locale.

I gave profiled the two versions using gcc and libstdc++. According to my profiling results (which should really be *your* profiling results) the program spends about half of its time in the `strtod` function. Other significant contributors are `dynamic_cast` (which is necessary for locale handling, which is necessary for string reading) and the `std::istream::sentry` constructor.

The iterator program parses strings according to arbitraty, possibly user-supplied locale facets. It spends most of its time in `std::num_get::do_get`, which is a *virtual* function; it in turn divides its time between internal functions `std::num_get::_M_extract_float` and `std::__convert_to_v<double>`. The former parses the number in order to find out which range of characters to pass to `strtod`. The latter just calls `strtod`, which parses and converts the number. So it appears that the iterator version parses each number twice.

I don't really know if it's feasible to squash the two parsing passes into one. Perhaps nobody cares to do this optimisation. Everybody knows that iostreams formatting is bad bas and should only be used in non-performance-critical applications, and it's due to an overhaul and replacement anyway.